# How should I do in MSSQL with count 'Grand total' and 'Difference from previous period' in diffrent datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server with data like below:

| year | quarter | month | week | totla_number | normal_number | abnormal_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 4 | 11 | 45 | 250 | 203 | 47 |
| 2021 | 4 | 11 | 46 | 208 | 195 | 13 |
| 2021 | 4 | 11 | 47 | 222 | 200 | 22 |
| 2021 | 4 | 11 | 48 | 234 | 198 | 36 |
| 2021 | 4 | 12 | 49 | 200 | 155 | 45 |
| 2021 | 4 | 12 | 50 | 189 | 166 | 23 |
| 2021 | 4 | 12 | 51 | 304 | 294 | 10 |
| 2021 | 4 | 12 | 52 | 195 | 175 | 20 |
| 2021 | 4 | 12 | 53 | 268 | 215 | 53 |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 299 | 248 | 51 |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 301 | 284 | 17 |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 154 | 100 | 54 |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 233 | 205 | 28 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 165 | 100 | 65 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 299 | 287 | 12 |

totla_number = normal_number + abnormal_number

I want to count 'Grand total' and 'Difference from previous period'

by total, year, quarter, month, week

but when I count 'month', I don't konw how to do

desire data like below :

| year | quarter | month | totla_number | Grand | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 4 | 11 | 914 | 914 | null |
| 2021 | 4 | 12 | 1156 | 2070 | 242 |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 987 | 987 | null |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 | 464 | 1451 | -523 |

How should I do?

Code like below:

```
select *
    sum(totla_number) over (partition by year order by month) as Grand
    totla_number - lag(totla_number) over (partition by year order by month) as diff
from data
```

Comment: SO is no code writing service. Please show what you've tried so far and what exactly is still unclear to you.

Comment: how do you get to `1802` and `-26` ?

Comment: 914 + 888 = 1802 and 888 - 914 = 26

Comment: should that 888 not be 1156 ? The sum off all month 12 of quarter 4 ?

Comment: yes, it should be 1156, I jist give an example XD

Comment: with bad example data we cannot help you, fix it. We don't want to loose time because your data is wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, I already fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are correct that you need to use the `lag` function, but to get it working together with the group by you need some extra work, because you will not be able to access all the columns you need in the grouped query.

Therefor we must first get the basic totals using the group by,
end then use that result set to use the Lag function on.

As you can see in this query

```
select t.year,
       t.quarter,
       t.month,
       t.totla_number,
       t.normal_number,
       t.abnormal_number,
       case when row_number() over (partition by t.year, t.quarter order by t.year, t.quarter) > 1 then
                lag(t.totla_number, 1) over (order by t.year, t.quarter, t.month)
            else 0
       end 
       + 
       t.totla_number
       as Grand,

       t.totla_number       
       -
       case when row_number() over (partition by t.year, t.quarter order by t.year, t.quarter) > 1 then
                lag(t.totla_number, 1) over (order by t.year, t.quarter, t.month)
            else t.totla_number
       end 
       as [diff]
       
       
from   ( select d.year, 
                d.quarter,
                d.month,
                sum(d.totla_number) as totla_number,
                sum(d.normal_number) as normal_number,
                sum(d.abnormal_number) as abnormal_number
         from   data d
         group by d.year, 
                d.quarter,
                d.month
       ) t
```

Please look at this [DBFiddle with the full code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d488478e0876bfd7dd125c357f12ac5a)

the result is this

| year | quarter | month | totla_number | normal_number | abnormal_number | Grand | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 4 | 11 | 914 | 796 | 118 | 914 | 0 |
| 2021 | 4 | 12 | 1156 | 1005 | 151 | 2070 | 242 |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 987 | 837 | 150 | 987 | 0 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 | 464 | 387 | 77 | 1451 | -523 |

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as

( select d.year, 
                d.quarter,
                d.month,
                sum(d.totla_number) as totla_number,
                sum(d.normal_number) as normal_number,
                sum(d.abnormal_number) as abnormal_number
  from   data d
  group by d.year, 
                d.quarter,
                d.month)


select t.year,
       t.quarter,
       t.month,
       t.totla_number,
       t.normal_number,
       t.abnormal_number,
       sum(t.totla_number) over(partition by t.year order by t.year, t.month)
       as Grand,

       t.totla_number       
       -
       lag(t.totla_number, 1) over(partition by t.year order by t.year, t.month)

       as [diff]
       
       
from t
```